# How is the conditional function used in tandem with the find function in Excel or the likes?

Tags: excel, replace, find, libreoffice, anki

[image]

I'm formatting data of words soon to be added to my vocabulary deck in Anki, using Libreoffice Calc, and came across this insurmountable problem due to my little knowledge in Excel or the likes. I would appreciate your help, Excel pundits.

I look up "insurmountable" and the dictionary defines it as *too great to be overcome: an insurmountable problem.* As you can see, an example sentence is preceded by a colon, ":". For the formatting purpose, I intend to convert ":" to "~". However, some of the words do not come with an example sentence, hence without a colon, and the replace function I use `=REPLACE (A2, FIND(":", A2), 1, "~")` returns #VALUE! for them. As I intend to have a complete column ready for export, as a matter of workaround, I use the conditional function `=IF(FIND(":", A2) = "#VALUE!", A2, REPLACE(A2, FIND(":", A2), 1, "~"))'. According to my fallible logic, the F10 cell should be filled in with the value of A10.

What's at fault here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is to think that #VALUE is string. No, that's the type of error. The right formula would be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(":"; A2));A2;REPLACE(A2; FIND(":"; A2); 1; "~"))
```